# String interpolation tem uma performance melhor que string.Format?

Tags: c#, .net, string, concatenação-de-string, interpolação-de-string

Eu uso Resharper e há poucos dias eu comecei a usar alguns recursos do C# 6.

Em várias partes do código uso `string.Format()` e percebi que o Resharper sugere que esses trechos sejam substituídos por *string interpolation*.

A dúvida é: por que o Resharper sugere essa troca?

*String interpolation* tem uma performance melhor que `string.Format()` ou essa sugestão é apenas para tornar o código mais legível?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A melhor forma de descobrir, é testando. Fiz um teste simples:

```
using static System.Console;
using System.Diagnostics;
                    
public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var x = "";
        var sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) x = string.Format("teste de string formatada com resultado: {0}", i + 5);
        sw.Stop();
        WriteLine(sw.ElapsedTicks);
        sw.Restart();
        for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) x = $"teste de string formatada com resultado: {i + 5}";
        sw.Stop();
        WriteLine(sw.ElapsedTicks);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/6iwJSq). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gvjboZ). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/InterpolationPerformance.cs).

O melhor teste será feito em um ambiente controlado e não em um servidor compartilhado onde não se sabe o que está rodando. Executei algumas vezes. E no geral o resultado foi quase o mesmo.

Mas é importante notar que em outros padrões este resultado pode ser diferente. Este tipo de teste só diz sobre esta situação específica, mas se pode generalizar. Pode ser que montando o teste de outra forma dê um resultado diferente, mesmo que ele execute a mesma coisa. Para testar adequadamente é necessário entender profundamente as implementações para tentar achar os pontos onde cada um se destaca e ondem falham. Se a implementação mudar, o teste não serve mais.

Coloquei no [**SharpLab**](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgDABFAjANgYgdAYQPYDsDO2ANgKYDcAsAFCxroAiAlgIYDmu2+ALowMb6Uq1KAGYEAJjQB2OAG9qcRRMnyqS9XABuzAE5wAHnAC8cAESnBGpdr34A7sbi4SDgMpdsABzvMuvABYAFACUllZw9ujuulwhYVYAZth6gTZwjI4wZOlwADxwiDBFWelgYMEGjkgw6ABiyQC2voGmXCTcJHDAndVwSTpNXMzAzHC82A1wOu0ArkRDwNggcjAAvqYANDlgcACsoQrhke5ecYdWAOo6jG0AMozOgZEAokTMnvgkwAAqfADW+AOaiOdnQACV2kMdLEgeE+sk4KldDkTCUMvlCsVsowyhVDCYACStSGdbpoeD9QbDUbjSbTfBzBZLOQZHa7dbxDTHDyeM7Ay7XO4PEhPUGvd6fH7/QGc1bUVZAA=) para ver o código gerado e ambos usam o [`Format()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=net-6.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Mais informações na [documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). Como não está na documentação é detalhe de implementação e um dia pode mudar.

A grande vantagem não está na velocidade, mas na simplificação e comodidade. E O Resharper sugere porque é mais elegante, não porque é mais rápido.

Em C# 10 tem a *string* interpolada constante que faz uma diferença de performance. [Veja mais](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-10.0/constant_interpolated_strings?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Answer (score 10):

Não existe diferença nenhuma. O compilador vai chamar `string.Format()` sempre que você usar a notação $.

Em outras palavras, o IL gerado vai ser o mesmo. Portanto, não existe diferença de performance.

Fonte: https://roslyn.codeplex.com/discussions/570614