# Dúvida no comando FOR

Tags: c#

Boa tarde, sou iniciante em C# (faz nem 2 dias que comecei a estudar) e gostaria de uma explicação da linha:

```
WriteLine($"{n1:d2} x {n2:d2} = {n1 * n2:d2}");
```

Referente à esse código:

```
using static System.Console;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        for (int n1 = 1; n1 < 11; n1++) {
            for (int n2 = 1; n2 < 11; n2++){
                WriteLine($"{n1:d2} x {n2:d2} = {n1 * n2:d2}");
            }
            WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Se puderem me manda um vídeo que ensine utilizar o WriteLine dessa forma, agradeço rsrs! Pois não entendi a lógica do `$` e do `{}`.

Comment: https://www.marcioalthmann.net/2015/07/c-6-string-interpolation/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9354154/how-do-i-interpolate-strings

Comment: relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/93207/string-interpolation-tem-uma-performance-melhor-que-string-format

Comment: Possível duplicata de [O que significa o simbolo "$" antes de uma string?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/91117/o-que-significa-o-simbolo-antes-de-uma-string)

Comment: Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UFDxqX57eH0

Comment: O símbolo $ é um recurso recente adicionado ao C# chamado "Interpolação de string". Resumidamente, sempre que encontrar um símbolo $ antes de uma string, significa que os valores encontrados entre chaves {} dentro dessa string devem ser tratadas como expressões, e não como strings.