# Tirar Caracters de uma coluna no datagridviwer

Tags: c#

Estou com um probleminha, tenho uma datagridviwer que preencho uma tabela no banco de dados, só qua entes de preencher precioso tirar os pontos os traços do conteúdo da colunas. Tem como usar o Replace em uma coluna do datagridviewr, ou alguma outra forma de limpar os caracteres pra depois gravar no banco.

Segue meu código.

```
public void Inseri()
{
        conex1.Open();
        SqlCommand cadastro = new SqlCommand("usp_InseriCadastro", conex1);
        cadastro.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        for (int i = 0; i < dgw_cadastro.Rows.Count -1; i++)
        {
            cadastro.Parameters.Clear();
            cadastro.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NOME",dgw_cadastro.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
            cadastro.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SOBRENOME",dgw_cadastro.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
            cadastro.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DDD",Convert.ToInt32(dgw_cadastro.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value));
            cadastro.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TELEFONE",Convert.ToInt32(dgw_cadastro. Rows[i].Cells[3].Value));
            cadastro.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CPF",dgw_cadastro.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value);
            cadastro.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DATANASC",Convert.ToDateTime(dgw_cadastro.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value));
            cadastro.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        conex1.Close();
}
```

Comment: Tem se pode utilizar `replace` mesmo, qual a dificuldade?

Comment: Então pra falar a verdade eu não sei como usar o replace nesse código..

Comment: o .Value é um Objeto se não me engano, seria qual campo?

Comment: Então o value e o valor do campo que esta dentro da celula 4 do datagridwier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Basicamente:***

```
string cpf = $"{dgw_cadastro.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value}".Replace(".","").Replace("-",".");
cadastro.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CPF", cpf);
```

note que o `.Value` é do tipo `object` e para funcionar precisa ser convertido para texto (`string`) para utilizar o método `Replace`.

Comment: Virgilio obrigado pela ajuda era isso mesmo que precisava, agora me tira uma duvida, sou novato ainda na programação em c#, e gostaria da saber pra que server o $ no começo do código?

Comment: @JuniorGuerreiro é bem explicado https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/128043/usando-interpola%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-string-c-6/128284 ou https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/93207/string-interpolation-tem-uma-performance-melhor-que-string-format

Comment: Valeu obrigado.